# Uninstalling MySQL on Solaris

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have installed **MySQL 5.5.31 in Opensolaris**. When I tried starting the MySQL server, it says 
 bash: mysql: command not found
So, I decided to uninstall the whole lot and try doing again.
But I could not find any spporting documents online to do so, because either they refer to .rpm file unistallation pkgrm.
I used .tar extension and pkgrm is not supported in my machine.

Comment: There is no reason to "uninstall" and try again. You either extracted the files to your server, or you didn't, and if you did, then all you're doing with this approach is wasting time, because the result will be the same...  Most likely you just need to set your `$PATH` correctly so that bash can find the mysql binaries, or fully-qualify the or use the full path to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Check MySQL service use following  command:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

If  MySQL  process is running then first stop mysql process.

```
kill -9 mysql_pid
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Remove mysql base and data dir. By default it's location is `/usr/local/mysql`.
Use  following  command:

```
rm -r mysql
```

Start with fresh installation:
Ref this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-installation.html) or [this](https://coderwall.com/p/e23_ca) for MySQL  binary installation.